# Java socket connection with Qt

Tags: java, c++, qt, sockets

I'm trying to connect a very simple java socket client to a QTcpServer. However, while it connects, I can't send messages to and from. I have also tried connecting the java client to a java server (works nicely) and the Qt server to a qt client (also works nicely). But mixing them somehow doesn't..

Here's the Java client:

```
public class SocketClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String hostName = "10.57.140.129";
        int portNumber = 2010;

        try (
            Socket kkSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
             BufferedReader stdIn =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String fromServer;
            String fromUser;

            while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
                if (fromServer.equals("Test recieved. KKTHXBYE"))
                    break;

                fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
                if (fromUser != null) {
                    System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                    out.println(fromUser);
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
             System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
                hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

With the bits of the QTserver code that is relevant:

```
#include "socketserver.h"

SocketServer::SocketServer(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent) {
}

void SocketServer::StartServer(){
    if(!this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 2010)){
        qDebug() << "Could not start server";
    }else{
        qDebug() << "Listening...";
    }
}

void SocketServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor){
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Connecting...";
    SocketThread *thread = new SocketThread(socketDescriptor,this);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()),thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(newData(QByteArray)), this, SLOT(incomeData(QByteArray)));
    thread->start();
}

void SocketServer::incomeData(QByteArray newData){
    emit sendBack(newData);
}
```

Thread:

```
#include "socketthread.h"

SocketThread::SocketThread(qintptr ID, QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent) {
    this->socketDescriptor = ID;
}

void SocketThread::run(){
    //thread starts here
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Starting thread";
    socket = new QTcpSocket();
    if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor)){
        emit error(socket->error());
        return;
    }

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()), Qt::DirectConnection);

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Client Connected";
    writeBack("connected");

    exec();
}

void SocketThread::readyRead(){
    QByteArray incomeData = socket->readAll();

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Data in: " << incomeData;

    emit newData(incomeData);
}

void SocketThread::writeBack(QByteArray Data){
    socket->write(Data);
}

void SocketThread::disconnected(){
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Disconnected";

    socket->deleteLater();
    exit(0);
}
```

Like mentioned, the client connects, and these debug outputs are written:
924  Connecting...
924  Starting thread
924  Client Connected

But no matter what I try to write from the client, it never picks up on anything with the readyReady() function. Any ideas? Am I missing specific endings on the lines I'm writing? (I've tried \r\n and \0, they don't seem to do much)

Comment: Check Line-Terminators. If QT and java use different line terminators they could simply never detect the end of a line waiting for more data to come ... forever. You can also try sending/receiving based on a byte-protocol rather than strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are using line-based processing in Java but not in C++:

`in.readLine()` vs. `socket->readAll()`

and

`out.println(fromUser)` vs. `writeBack("connected");`

The C++ just never sends a CR/LF, which is not a problem when the other end does not expect one -> `readAll()`. The Java side however does expect (and send) CR/LF because you use `BufferedReader.readLine()` and `BufferedWriter.writeln()`.

Decide if you want line-based communication or not and then adapt the C++ or the Java side accordingly.

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you